# How does Visual Studio load libraries?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I have a solution with C#, C++ & C++/CLI projects. To be more specific: it is C++ core (~5 unmanaged dll's), C++/CLI core wrapper and C# assemblies with project-specific buisness logic.

Some time ago I figured out that VS 2008 form designer (WinForms) sometimes can't load core wrapper assembly. After a few hours spent with VS debugger and Procmon I found out that VS can't load assembly because it can't resolve unmanaged libraries that wrapper depends on. VS searches in every system folder and folder from PATH environment variable, but not in folder where wrapper assembly is located.

Moreover, I have 2 forms in one assembly, one is inherited from another: VS form designer loads parent form fine and fails with loading an inherited form.

So, here is my question: does anyone knows the reason of this behavior?

P.S. I used workaround: added folder with project binaries to PATH variable, but I still want to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the binaries into the executables folder? Because i'm sure that .NET is only searching for know paths ( As path's stored in **%PATH%** ) and the local folder of the executable.

I don't know the exact reason for this, but i think this is because the DLL doesn't know the path where it has been loaded from ( managed DLL's do! ) and only looking in the current directory and other known paths.

But there are a workaround for this, you could create a startup executable for Visual-Studio and do one of the following things:

- Modify the **%PATH%** variable with [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx)
- Use the **Kernel32.dll** method `SetDllDirectory`

**SetDllDirectory-Snippet:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Boolean SetDllDirectory(String pathName);
```